# Edit date format of Blog post and comments

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, blog

I'm trying to change the date format of blog posts and comments in Post.aspx, but having trouble. What I want to do is change the `$thisNode/@PublishedDate` value with `$thisNode/@PublishedDate.MonthDayOnly`, but I cannot find where to do that.

I've tried editing blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx with SharePoint designer, but because it doesn't render the actual blog post (i.e. there's no `?ID=2` in the design view of SPD), I cannot select the date to edit the formula, like I can with the blog home page.

I also tried editing blog.xsl in my hive, but nothing changes on the blog post view (unsurprisingly?)

Can anyone point me in the right direction so I can locate and change the formula for the Post.aspx post view and comment views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this helps you:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/customize-sharepoint-2010-blog-post/

It basically consists of:

1. Make a copy of the blog.xsl from hive.
2. Make your changes to the copy.
3. Edit your Posts.aspx in SPD.
4. Modify the XslLink property of the Posts webpart to point to your custom blog.xsl

Comment: Thanks for the link. Between that and another link I found, I was able to work out where and how to edit the xsl (my link: http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2011/12/customize-blog-posts-in-sharepoint-2010.html)